# Liferay Hooks plugins folder

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 version.
I am trying to Learn Liferay, due to its importance.

I am into the Liferay Hooks concept, for this I am following this site:

http://kamalkantrajput.blogspot.com/2009/05/using-hooks-in-liferay-for-customizing.html

In this the author mentions about this below:
Go to plugins/hooks create a folder with any name. eg asset-publisher-hook

Please tell me where can i find the plugins folder? 
Because inside the Liferay Tomcat, I found 6 folders with the name plugins and no folder hooks under this .

Please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to read the documentation in the Liferay Wiki:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins

In a Nutshell: once you have created the hook plugin (as described by adarshr) you can simply deploy the portlet like any other portlet.

If you want to remove the hook, make sure to undeploy it while Tomcat is **running**. Otherwise Liferay will not be informed about it and the original JSPs won't be restored.

Un-deploying can be done by simply deleting the portlet's directory in the Tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: Thank you very much and horse , i have one more question , can i use the hooks concept for showing My Custom JSP page which is under my Portlet . Thank you very much .

Comment: If you want to use a JSP that's inside your portlet to be shown in one of the Liferay portlets, then the answer is no. You have to create a JSP hook to customize a Liferay portlet.

Comment: Thank you Horse , as told i have created a JSP Hook , please see the screen shot updated under my question , please let me know what JSP Page i need to override under Liferay ??

Comment: I don't know what those screenshots show. But I simply go into the ROOT webapp and find the portlet and JSP page I want to override there (I currently don't have access to a computer with Liferay installed, so I cannot be more detailed)

Comment: Ok , my actual requirement is that i dont want to show that default Liferay Control Panel page on liferay startup , i want to show my custom page , that  is what i was trying .

Comment: Which page exactly do you mean? I don't think I understand the "on startup" part.

Comment: The page which consists of Bruno login , and other logins the dockbar

Comment: That is not a plugin, that is a simple page with WebContent on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Plugins SDK which can be downloaded from http://www.liferay.com/downloads. Select "Plugins SDK" in the dropdown and click download.

Once you extract it, open a command prompt in the hooks folder. Then you execute the command `create asset-publisher-hook "Asset Publisher Hook"` and it will create the basic hooks project for you.